# Failed to copy item to a file share. Illegal characters in path. Nintex workflow

Tags: html-escape-characters, nintex-workflow

I am trying to use the Nintex workflow method 'Copy to Fileshare"  and get an error: "Failed to copy item to a file share. Illegal characters in path. "

the string that is the proven path is:

\xxxxxxxx.xx.xx.xx.xxx\services\research\HAVEEN

So I assume it is the dot '.' character.  Any thoughts on how I could rewrite the string so the method does not throw the error?

tx

dave

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, What is Nintex's notion of what the current drive letter is? I assume you are running in a  Windows environment, in which case you should supply a fully qualified path including the drive.

Second, try using forward slashes "/" instead of backslashes. Some applications prefer forward slashes as more platform-neutral path delimiters.

Third, check the documentation to see if some characters in pathnames need to be escaped. That might include a dot character, although that would be unusual.